# Two AndroidManifest.xml files, which one is relevant

Tags: android, manifest

I am learning to develop android apps from [android site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). As you can see here they talk about `AndroidManifest.xml` . My project seems to have two such files , with diffferent content.

One located at : `workspace\MyFirstApp`

Having contents

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

ANother located at `workspace\MyFirstApp\bin` and having below contents , in addition to what the first file has

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

I am not sure why there are two `AndroidManifest.xml` . Also which one is my main one being used by my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `workspace\MyFirstApp\bin` is automatically build on Build where as 
`workspace\MyFirstApp` this is your projects `Manifest` which you can modify and alter this is you main `Manifest`

**Note:** **Bin** and **Gen** Contents are **automatically generated** You shall not bother about them you can check by Cleaning the project both got emptied and on Rebuilding or Running again **Gen and Bin** Contents **are recreated**

Answer (score 2):

bin folder is automatically created when you run your application.You don't need to bother about that.The original Android manifest file is the one in your work space.You can make all possible changes there and when you run your application it will automatically reflect in your bin folder.